# Where can I get the population allele frequency vcf file?

Tags: vcf, variant-calling, gatk, quality-control, wgs

I want to use [GATK](https://software.broadinstitute.org/gatk) to estimate cross-sample contamination for Whole Genome Sequencing data.

The specific tool is [ContEst](https://software.broadinstitute.org/gatk/documentation/tooldocs/current/org_broadinstitute_gatk_tools_walkers_cancer_contamination_ContEst.php) and it is run with:

```
java
 -jar GenomeAnalysisTK.jar \
 -T ContEst \
 -R reference.fasta \
 -I:eval tumor.bam \
 -I:genotype normal.bam \
 --popfile populationAlleleFrequencies.vcf \
 -L populationSites.interval_list
 [-L targets.interval_list] \
 -isr INTERSECTION \
 -o output.txt
```

The `--popfile` option requires a vcf file representing population allele frequencies. Where can I get it? Is it the one I can get from [dbSNP](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/SNP/index.html)?

I'm using the human_g1k_v37.fasta reference, a version of hg19, "for the phase1 analysis we mapped to GRCh37. Our fasta file which can be found here called human_g1k_v37.fasta.gz, it contains the autosomes, X, Y and MT but no haplotype sequence or EBV".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the [GATK forum](https://gatkforums.broadinstitute.org/gatk/discussion/8897/which-one-should-i-use-for-contest-popfile) they've recommended [the population stratified VCF file](ftp://gsapubftp-anonymous@ftp.broadinstitute.org/bundle/b37/hapmap_3.3_b37_pop_stratified_af.vcf.gz) for this purpose.